Is it possible to find \ create setup files for SQL Server 2022 with CU, not RTM?
Is it possible to find \ create setup files for SQL Server 2022 with CU, not RTM?
Reason:
Can't upgrade SQL Server from 2019 to 2022 in cluster with AG and CDC due this one bug:
Fixes an issue in which applying a patch on the secondary replica or performing an in-place upgrade fails if a database has change data capture (CDC) enabled and is in an availability group.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/sql/releases/sqlserver-2022/cumulativeupdate6#2442348
This bug was fixed in SQL Server 2022 CU6.
So in order to upgrade my cluster I need to run setup of SQL Server 2022 CU6, not SQL Server 2022 RTM.
Turn off CDC \ remove AG - VERY BIG problem.
Or is it any other ways to solve my problem?

Maybe install a fresh instance with no databases, upgrade CU, then add to AG and set as primary, then take down the other and do the same?

I can't find anything for 2022 explicitly, but it's probably the same.  What you are describing is slipstreaming, here is one link. https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/6466/slipstream-installation-of-service-packs-and-cumulative-updates-on-sql-server-2016-and-higher/


Is it possible to find \ create setup files for SQL Server 2022 with CU, not RTM?

Yes, there is a command line option called UpdateSource that can be used. Download and extract the CU you're targeting (hopefully the latest available) and use that folder as the target for the option.


Reason: Can't upgrade SQL Server from 2019 to 2022 in cluster with AG and CDC due this one bug [...]

You don't need to do this via command line if you don't want to. Kick out a replica, pave it, install 2022, update to the latest CU, bring back into the cluster, add it as a replica and seed/restore.
In-place upgrades, in my opinion, have no place in a topology such as this.
